# How to increase customer session time

Tags: customer, shopping-cart

How can I increase the amount of time a customer gets to shop in a store? My login/ cart clears after 10 minutes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to `System > Configuration > Web > Session Cookie Management` and set Cookie Lifetime

Comment: @Matthew McLennan: I don't know how you marked above answer by mbalparda as accepted rather that was for admin panel

Comment: @ Anurag Khandelwal, please tell me how to increase the session timeout for the customers?

Comment: There is no "Session Cookie Management"

Answer (score 4):

For **Magento 2.1.x** ~ Go to **Stores > Settings > Configuration > General > Web > Default Cookie Settings > Cookie Lifetime**

Comment: I set my value to above 800 hours but I still get logged out after a short while.